# Two-way binding faulty when used with a popup directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

i am trying angularjs modal popup directive. in that popup i have used tabs and panes directive. i 
have a two 
textbox(both having same ng-model=myName), one in my main page and one in my popup. if i change the 
value in main page it is getting updated in popup textbox, but when i change the popup textbox the main page textbox is not getting updated. how to fix it.

```
// html page
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html ng-app="modalDemo">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>modal popup</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.8.1.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/route1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/controller.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/scripts.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="bodyCtrl">
<br />
 <input type="text" ng-model="myName" />
<button ng-click="primaryAction()">click to load default text</button> <br /><br />

<button modal-open="myModal"> click me</button>

<popup modal-id="myModal" modal-type="tabs" show-header="false" header-title="Modal Header">

<tabs>
<pane title="first">
    <input type="text" name="myName" ng-model="myName">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="primaryAction()">save</button>
</pane>
<pane title="second">
    <h3>content2</h3>
</pane>
<pane title="Third">
    <h3>content3</h3>
</pane>

</tabs>
```

i have posted my code in my fiddle. [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Zd7ax/3/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because there are two different scopes where one is the parent of the other. When no `myName` property exists on the child scope, the child scope gets `myName` from the parent scope. That is, when you change the value in the outer input (which is connected to the parent scope), the input inside the tabs directive gets updated. But when you edit the value of the input field inside the tabs, the value gets written to the new `myName` property on the child scope, and `myName` is no longer connected between the parent and child scope.

If you want to share ng-models like that, make sure that your model contains a dot. Something like `myModel.myName` instead of just `myName`. That will cause JavaScript to first look for `myModel` on the child scope, but since the child scope doesn't have a `myModel`, it looks for it in the parent scope and sets `myName` on that object.

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Zd7ax/30/